# Plain Javascript Select Option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown with 3 options and a textbox. About the dropdown, The top one is just empty , 2nd and 3rd have values. When I toggled between these 3 options, I managed to output 2nd and 3rd value in the textbox but not the 1st option value (i just want an empty textbox when option 1 selected).. How to do this?

Check my code please..

```
function price(){
if (document.getElementById("fruits").selectedIndex < 1) { document.getElementById("fruitprice").value = "" }
if (document.getElementById("fruits").selectedIndex == 1) { document.getElementById("fruitprice").value = (2).toFixed(2); }
if (document.getElementById("fruits").selectedIndex == 2) { document.getElementById("fruitprice").value = (3).toFixed(2); }
}

<span style="font-family: Calibri; font-weight: bold;">Choose Fruit</span>:
<br>
<select id="fruits" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) price();" />
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<input type="text" size="2" id="fruitprice" />
```

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: Just remove if condition from your html onchange event.. as selected first will have 0 index that is false so your function will not called

Comment: Thank you so much! yogenSolved! Got that.. :) .. everyone answers helped!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided *any* code, i am going to assume the following

1. You are trying to do this via a `change` event of the drop-down
2. You are using jQuery

Your `select` markup

```
<select id="selectNum">
    <option value="0"></option>        
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

and the `input`

```
<input id="txtSomething" type="text">
```

Your `onchange` handler

```
$('#selectNum').on('change', function() {
   $('#txtSomething').val(this.value)
})
```

This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your code ?
This is example maybe can help you :

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="one"></a></li>
      <li><a class="two">Value 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="hree">Value 3</a></li>
    </ul>
<textarea placeholder="enter value" id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Jquery :

```
<script>
  $(".one").click(function(){
    $("#textarea").val($(this).text());
  });
  $(".two").click(function(){
    $("#textarea").val($(this).text());
  });
  $(".three").click(function(){
    $("#textarea").val($(this).text());
  });
</script>
```

If you are using options on select with class dropdown, you can use change() function

Answer (score 0):

You could try James' solution (using jQuery). The plain `JavaScript` "version" would be something like this:

**HTML**

```
<select id="ddl" onchange="ShowValue(this.value)">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<div>
<input type="text" id="txtDisplay">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function ShowValue(val){
    document.getElementById('txtDisplay').value = val;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VashTS/osefskm7/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove if condition from your html onchange event.. as selected first will have 0 index that is false so your function will not called – yogen darji

Thank you yogen and everyone else. :)